# Detecting scroll to bottom pixel on back to top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, back

I have this solution for back to top button.

HTML:

```
<div id='toTop'>To The Top!</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

CSS:

```
#toTop {
    padding: 5px 3px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/fjXSq/

It's working. But ı want when scroll to bottom 200px, get scroll button to me. How can I set this option?

Comment: sorry, but i don't get what you want?? also your "Scroll to top" doesn't provide a functionality like scrolling tot op..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($('html').height() - $(window).height() - 200)) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
```